# Update Manager problems

Tags: 10.04, update-manager, partial-upgrade, blacklist

I'm running Lucid and whenever I open Update Manager, it says I should run a partial upgrade. I think this may have happened when I was trying to update and my computer shut off. So I click Partial Upgrade and while it's calculating the changes, it gives me an error. It says:

```
Could not calculate upgrade
An unresolvable problem occurred while calculating the upgrade.
The package update-manager-kde is marked for removal but it is in
the removal blacklist. This can be caused by:
 * Upgrading to a pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Running the current pre-release version of Ubuntu
 * Unofficial software packages not provided by Ubuntu

This is most likely a transient problem, please try again later.
```

This is extremely frustrating, and every time I try to upgrade, this happens. I might just try `sudo apt-get install -f` to fix it, but that's all I can think of to fix this problem.

EDIT:

`sudo apt-get install -f` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use KDE you can remove the package with
`sudo apt-get remove update-manager-kde`
and run the update-manager again.